# Custom DataPager for ListView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, listview, datapager

> I'd like to get both C# and VB.NET suggestion.

I have the follow DataPager to handle the paging of ListView.

DataPager mark-up

```
 <asp:DataPager ID="dpComputer" runat="server" 
        PagedControlID="lvComputer" PageSize="10">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False"  />
            <asp:NumericPagerField NumericButtonCssClass="dpTimeSheet" ButtonCount="100" ButtonType="Image" />
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowPreviousPageButton="False"  />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
```

handling DataPager event

```
        Protected Sub lvComputer_PagePropertiesChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lvComputer.PagePropertiesChanged
    
            LoadData()
      
        End Sub
```

show/hide datapager

```
    Protected Sub lvComputer_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lvComputer.DataBound

        dpComputer.Visible = dpComputer.PageSize <= dpComputer.TotalRowCount

    End Sub
```

The code above makes the following output:

> First Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 and so on Next Last

The code I have above works fine. However,when TotalRows of ListView lvComputer is more than 200, there are a lot of paging number on the page.
I want to show paging number like something in the following format:

> First Previous 1 2 3 ..... 9 10 11 Next Last
>
> First Previous 5 6 7 8 ..... 13 14 15 16 Next Last

What do I need to do programmatically to modify the datapager to get the desired result like above example? Thank you.